# Redux-Observable : find() doesn't return anything

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

I'm very new to RxJs and have only used Redux (+Thunk) so far, so I'm trying to understand how everything works together. I'm currently trying to fetch a user from a source (json file) with data submitted from a login form.

**authEpic.js**

```
    import users from '../api/users.json';
    
    const source = of(users);
    
    export const authEpic = (action$) => action$.pipe(
    ofType("AUTH_LOGIN_REQUEST"),
    switchMap(({ authData }) => source.pipe(
        find(user => authData.email === user.email && authData.password === user.password),
        map(user => ({ type: "RESULTS", results: user }))
    ))
);
```

But nothing is returned even though it says the value returned as properties. I'd like to understand how to find a user and pass it to another action as I'm pretty much clueless at the moment despite looking here and there.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `of(users)` emits a single value: whatever `users` is, presumably an array. So inside your `find()` the param `user` is actually the full `users`, not an individual user, thus `users.email === undefined`. The `find()` operator acts similarly to Array's `find()` in that it will always return (emit) a single value, so if nothing is found, that value that is returned (emitted) is literally the value `undefined`. That's what is happening here. You're emitting an action `{ type: 'RESULTS', results: undefined }`

If `users` is indeed an array, you probably want to use `from(users)` so that each user is emitted by the Observable one-by-one. Then it works as I imagine you are expecting. Here's a demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/redux-observable-playground-rararm?file=index.js

If this ends up as production code you'll want to handle the case where no user match is found.

---

As an aside, I imagine this isn't production code (having all passwords in clear text as a json file locally) but for anyone reading this it might be helpful still to note that, in this particular case, it probably would have been more clear to just use an array instead of an Observable:

```js
export const authEpic = (action$) =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType('AUTH_LOGIN_REQUEST'),
    // Note this is now `map` instead of `switchMap`
    map(({ authData }) => {
      const user = users.find(
        (user) =>
          authData.email === user.email && authData.password === user.password
      );

      // Some how handle no match (e.g. wrong email or password)
      if (!user) {
        return { type: 'NO_RESULTS' };
      }

      return { type: 'RESULTS', results: user };
    })
  );
```